# Insert a character in a String before a specific character

Tags: java

I need to change a string as follow : 
Adding a "\" before any founded special character here an example : 
If the string = ${Name} the result should be ===> \${NAME}

I wrote this :

```
private static String getFormattedString(String variable) {
  char [] specialCharacters = {'.', '\\', '+', '*', '?', '[', '^', ']', '$', '(', ')' ,'{' ,'}', '=', '!', '<', '>', '|', ':', '-'};
  String old = variable;
  String formatted = "";
  int i=0;
  while(i<old.length()) {
    for (int j=0;j<specialCharacters.length;j++) {

if (old.charAt(i) == specialCharacters[j]) {
  formatted+=old.substring(0, i)+"\\"+old.substring(i, i+1);
  old=variable.substring(i+1,variable.length());
  break;
} 
  }
  i++;
}
return formatted;
}
```

But i'm getting a wrong result :

```
 Formatted String : ++++> \${NAME\}
```

I'm really confused, any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: If you just want to escape the `$`, why do you have `{` and `}` in your list of special characters?

Comment: ... and additionally, as `{` and `}` are in the list of special characters, your implementation has a bug. It does not escape the first `{`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose " It does not escape the first {" yes this is my problem thank u.

Comment: In the `if` you need to do `++i;` too, to skip the backslash. And then the variable juggling could be reduced. But the StringBuilder answer is more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static final List<Character> SPECIAL = Arrays.asList('.', /* etc */);

public static String escape(final String input)
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    final CharBuffer buf = CharBuffer.wrap(input);
    char c;

    while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
        c = buf.get();
        if (SPECIAL.contains(c))
            sb.append('\\');
        sb.append(c);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

(`CharBuffer` is underused, even though it is the best way to iterate over a `String`'s characters!)

---

If you use Guava 15+, you can also write your own [`CharEscaper`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/escape/CharEscaper.html); like everything Guava, it works wonderfully well!

Comment: @AmiraGL yes, _do_ check Guava... You'll eventually find you can't do without it :p

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to escape any special characters, try using `StringEscapeUtils` from Apache Commons:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
(...)
    String result = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `String.replaceAll()`

```
String strgg  = "${Name}";
System.out.println(strgg.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$"));
```

Output:

```
\${Name}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use replaceAll function

```
private static String getFormattedString(String variable) {
  //No need this.
  // char [] specialCharacters = {'.', '\\', '+', '*', '?', '[', '^', ']', '$', '(', ')' ,'{' ,'}', '=', '!', '<', '>', '|', ':', '-'};
  variable = variable.replaceAll(".","\\."); //same for all.
  variable = variable.replaceAll("+","\\+");.
  variable = variable.replaceAll("*","\\*");
return formatted;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you escape the `\\` first, then.

Comment: I am sure this is going to work as AmiraGL asked for.

Comment: Won't work. 1. strings are immutable; 2. the first argument to `.replaceAll()` is a regex.

Comment: My point was just that you have to escape the \\ first, otherwise you will escape all those previously inserted \\s as well. But as pointed out by fge, there are indeed more severe problems...

Comment: @fge :~ I think your both problem satisfy now.

Comment: Please run your code and see what happens. Say you have the string "$hello", now you escape the $, you have "\\$hello", now you replace \\, you get "\\\\$hello", thus you have to escape the \\ first. Also, you have to escape those ., +, * in the first argument as those are regexes.

Comment: ok this is special case for '\' but if i set replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\"); at very first then i dont think this will make an issue. right?